# Find the closest point of a lattice $\Lambda$ given the closest point for its union of cosets $\bigcup_i ({\bf r}_i+\Lambda)$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, lattices, euclidean-lattices

Suppose we have an $n$-dimensional lattice $\Lambda$, and a set of vectors ${\bf r}_i$, we can construct a union of cosets of $\Lambda$, denoted as $L$, as
$$
L \equiv \bigcup_i ({\bf r}_i+\Lambda)
$$
In general $L$ needs not be a lattice, but let's assume so and in fact I am interested in the case where $L$ is the D-type root lattice $D_n$. Given a point ${\bf x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, since we have fast algorithm to find the closest point in $D_n$, as shown [here](http://neilsloane.com/doc/Me83.pdf), my question is if we can use that, or any other methods, to find the closest point in $\Lambda$.

Note that the reverse question has been answered in the above cited paper, namely that if we know the closest point in $\Lambda$, denoted as $\Phi({\bf x})$, then we can quickly find $y_i\equiv \Phi({\bf x} -{\bf r}_i)+{\bf r}_i$, followed by comparing their distances to ${\bf x}$ to find the closest point in $L$.

It would be properly helpful to have an example. Consider a lattice $\Lambda$ generated by
$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$

where the row vectors are the basis vectors, which all have even sum of components. Hence the lattice is a sublattice of $D_9$. <s>With some numerical experiments, I am convinced that the last four basis vectors times $1/2$, together with ${\bf 0}$, constitute the five ${\bf r}_i$ vectors such that</s>
$
\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{D_9 = \bigcup_{i=0}^5 ({\bf r}_i+\Lambda).}
$

[EDIT: The above strikethrough statement is incorrect. As pointed by Noam in the comment, there should be 16 coset vectors. They are vectors of the form $[0,0,0,0,a,b,c,d,e]$ where $a,b,c,d,e=0\text{ or }1$. Since there can only be even number of 1's, we have ${5\choose 2}+{5\choose 4}+1=16$ vectors.]

[EDIT 2: I have edited this part multiple times, since I don't know how to find the coset systematically in this case. If anyone knows, please let me know.]

If this is the case, is there a simple way to find the closest point in $\Lambda$, given that we can find that for $D_9$ pretty easily?

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: It seems the example must be wrong as written: the D9 lattice has covolume 2, and your sublattice's basis vectors form a matrix with determinant 32, so it should take 32/2 = 16 cosets to generate D9, not 6.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies You are right, my numerical experiments just show that the ${\bf r}_i$ should take the form $[0,0,0,0,a,b,c,d,e]$ for integers $a,b,c,d,e$. I will see if I can figure out the explicit form of ${\bf r}_i$s.